# Updating file on heroku server

Tags: python, heroku

I deploy python app on heroku. It's doing a very simple thing. Parse HTML, get some data and save in to csv file. When I'm starting it app crush when should write to file (It's works locally). I think heroku prevents from operating files on a server.

How to resolved that?

Comment: Heroku does not really allow you to persist files. Use a database instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku is a read-only file system and does not allow writing, except for small temporary files.  Heroku recommends S3 for writing files.  I've never done this using Python (only Ruby), but [the docs](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/s3_tut.html) seem pretty good.